# Media uploads working incorrectly

Tags: wordpress

I recently migrated a WP site (taken over from other vendor), but after the migration, media upload is having problem.

1. File is uploaded to wrong directory (2017/month folder instead of 2018/month folder, checked using FTP)
2. Thumbnail does not show on media gallery. File name and file size also not showing. (Opening the file URL works)

Has anyone come across such issue before? 
How did you fix it?

Comment: How exactly did you migrate your wordpress site? Because you need both the entries in the wp_posts table (type attachment) pointing to the right location, and the files readable on disk. I never had issues with images when migrating WordPress websites, if you copy the database and uploads directory nothing really can go wrong. So I wonder how you did it?

Comment: Thanks @berend , turns out it was a DB autoincrement issue. Solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently when migration, the db script was exported from phpmyadmin but my new server uploaded the script through adminer.

Somehow, posts and post_meta tables did not get auto-increment, causing the failures.

Thanks to all who have taken a look at this. Hope the solution helps anyone with similar issue.